# Directory.EnumerateFiles search pattern does not work on file shares

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.2

According to the [Microsoft Docs site for Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_), the search pattern parameter will match any extension beginning with the specified pattern when it is exactly 3 characters.  However, this is not working on file shares, only local drives.

For a directory of `\\share\folder\` containing a single file named `file.xlsx`, this first code snippet does not return it:

```
public static List<string> GetAllFilesFromDirectory(string directory) =>
   new[] { "*.csv", "*.xls", "*.txt" }.SelectMany(ext => Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, ext)).ToList();
```

However, if I add the `*.xlsx` pattern, it does return it:

```
public static List<string> GetAllFilesFromDirectory(string directory) =>
   new[] { "*.csv", "*.xls", "*.xlsx", "*.txt" }.SelectMany(ext => Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, ext)).ToList();
```

I also tested this with the same file in the `C:\temp` directory and it found returned it both ways.

This is running in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 console app.

Am I missing something in the search pattern?  Or does this not work with file shares the same way as local drives?  Would this be expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be the unluckiest person, to have hit this bug. I can confirm that it behaves as per your observation, and also couldn't find any references to this anywhere on the interwebs.

So I traced the .NET source code to see how `Directory.EnumerateFiles` works and - deep within the bowels - eventually ran into a [call](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs#L272) to `FindFirstFile` and subsequent `FindNextFile` calls. These were PInvoked directly from the kernel, so you can't get any lower than that.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
```

Well gotta test that then. Guess what? It catches the XLSX file in local directories, but not in network shares.

[The doc for the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) does not mention this behaviour either. So yeah. You've just hit an undocumented "feature" :)

*Edit: This just got better.* Looks like in **.NET Core** (from 2.0 all the way to .NET 5) this behaviour isn't there anymore. They actually wrote their own [pattern matcher](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dbe6447aa29b14150b7c6dd43072cc75f0cdf013/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Enumeration/FileSystemName.cs#L102) this time round. `*.xls` would not catch XLSX in any folders, local or otherwise. Yet [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0) still says that it should.

**Edit 2021**: The doco has now been [updated](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/4052) with a remark about the quirk on .NET Framework.

---

Here's my test code for the `FindFirstFile` call:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Ensure these test folders only contain ONE file.
        // Name the file "Test.xlsx"
        Test(@"C:\Temp\*.xls"); // Finds the xlsx file just fine
        Test(@"\\Server\Temp\*.xls"); // But not here!
    }

    public static void Test(string fileName)
    {
        Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
        var hnd = Win32Native.FindFirstFile(fileName, out data);

        if (hnd == Win32Native.InvalidPtr) 
            Debug.WriteLine("Not found!!");
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("Found: " + data.cFileName);
    }
}

/** Windows native Pinvoke **/
public class Win32Native
{
    public static IntPtr InvalidPtr = new IntPtr(-1);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
    {
        public uint dwFileAttributes;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
        public uint nFileSizeHigh;
        public uint nFileSizeLow;
        public uint dwReserved0;
        public uint dwReserved1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string cFileName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string cAlternateFileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good investigation. I wonder if we'd see a difference if we were to use the wide versions of the calls explicitly. I suspect depending on which is used, it calls legacy code that isn't long filename aware and somehow truncates the extension.